# Number Theory Question on Archimedes Condition

Tags: number-theory, foundations

In Foundations of Mathematics, it states that

> "If $x$ and $y$ are different numbers on the line and we wish to distinguish between them, all we need do is find $n$ such that $1/10^n$ is less than their difference: then their expansion to $n$ places will differ."

Wouldn't a more accurate statement be "is less than or equal to their difference" ? For example, $0.08$ and $0.09$ differ by $1/10^2$ where $n = 2$, but $.01$ (the difference) is not less than $1/10^2$.

Comment: I think you missed the point. To 2 decimal places 0.08 and 0.09 agree.  You need to use $10^{-3}$ to get the difference in the third decimal place.

Comment: @herbsteinberg you sure about that?  If some says "expand $\frac 9{110}$ to two decimal places" do then mean $0.1$ or $0.08$?

Comment: I think more to the point is we can't assume we know without taking both number to infinitude we don't wish to presume to *know* they differ by *exactly* $10^{-n}$.  And there is the posibility that $0.08$ and $0.0899999999999......$ differ by *exactly* $10^{-2}$ but they are the same in the first two decimal places.  It's kind of a minor point.  I'd like to read the entire section in context to get a clearer picture of what the big "point" the author is trying to make.

Comment: "Foundations of Mathematics" by whom?

Comment: My mistake.  My mind was thinking 1/80 and 1/90.

Comment: Okay, I googled.  In spirit, I think the idea is we don't know to exactitude.  And in practice we can have an infinite expansion with two representations.  $0.09 = 0.0899999999......$

Comment: ... or on third reading... maybe the author wanted the simplest explaination.  A "more accurate" statement isn't always a *better* statement.  $\le$ implies $<$ so $<$ is sufficient.  What we lose in tossing out the minor cases where they are *exactly* equal, is not very important compared to what we gain in clarity and the universally always truth of $<$.

Comment: ... but even so... in  the example Stewart and Tall give $a_0.a_1a_2a_3....a_n \le x < a_0.a_1a_2a_3....a_n + \frac 1{10^n}$ would be thrown a monkey wrench if there were trailing 9s.  But that's not the real point, I think.  The real point I think is they derived their result algebraicly.  The logic that *well* if the two numbers are *exactly* equal then we'd have a case we we didn't have to go so far (although we could) is post-hoc.

Comment: .. tl;dr... yes, *if* the numbers are *exactly* off by $10^{-n}$ and *if* there are no trailing 9s, then, yes, that would be more accurate.  But accuracy is not the point.  Universal application is.